# angular digest loop and very large model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

I have 1000 root items. Each of these items has 4 child items. Each of these items has 2 collections of ~100 elements which can be edited.
These elements are lazy loaded, but in worst scenario there could be: 1000*4*2*100 = 800k elements which can be edited.

I want do enable button if there is any edition.
I wrote function on each level to determine if element is edited, and if parent has any edited elements.
Also root container has isEdited function which enables/disables button.

But calling this function on each digest loop seems not to be optimal, Because edition does not happened to often.

Is there a solution in angular for this problem?
I mean something like in knockout.js where parent property can observes child properties and changes its value only when edition occurs.
So that in my case isEdition won’t be calculate on each digest loop. But updated when edition occurs.

I profile my code and found that isEdited() function takes most cpu time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$scope.$watch('bigObjectWithNesting', 
    function(newV, oldV) { $scope.isEditedFlag = ...; },
    true);
```

or your method call. And use `isEditedFlag` in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you `watch` it will always be calculate on each digest. You might use `ng-change` on each root element and set isEditing flag to true. You might need something more but this could be one approach I think.